# What is the easiest way to insert Thai words in an English lyx document?

Tags: xetex, lyx

I am a big fan of Lyx, but find that when I want to include a few Thai words within an English document, things start getting difficult.

There are many solutions posted online, not all of which are easy to follow for non-TeX-experts like myself.  Some of the solutions appear not to work with Lyx.

What is the easiest way to insert Thai words into an English Lyx document?

Answer (score 2):

After trying several methods, the most efficient way I have found is to do the following:

For all of the following you need to go be in Document Settings, which is in the "Document" menu.

1. In the "LaTeX Preamble", add this:

   ```
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont{Norasi}
   \XeTeXlinebreaklocale ’th_TH’
   ```
2. In the "Fonts" section, tick "Use non-TeX fonts (via XeTeX/LuaTeX)".
3. In the "Output" section, Default Output format box, choose "PDF (XeTeX)".
4. Press "OK".

When you click "view" or "update" document, you will now see a PDF which should show both Thai and English words correctly.

- This makes it easy to switch between Thai and English: no ERT is
  required in the document.
- Credit for part 1 of this approach goes to this document:
  http://htl10.users.sourceforge.net/Languages/TypesettingThaiWithLaTeX.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The same issue I had there and babel's `\selectlanguage{thai}` is easiest in my case.

1. Go to `Document --> Settings --> Language`

   - Set `Language` to **Thai**.
   - Set `Encoding` to **Other**: **Thai (TIS 620-0)**
   - Set `Language Package` to **Custom** and enter `\usepackage[main=english,thai]{babel}`
2. At any part of the document where Thai words should appear, insert TeX command (Press CTRL+L) and enter `\selectlanguage{thai}` and change the language back to English with `\selectlanguage{english}`, otherwise section headings will be in Thai.